# Including Javascript files in a Chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, include, content-script

I'm writing a Chrome extension, and want to write one JS file, that provides several expected functions that aren't present in another, then load that other file. I'm after behavior similar to `require` in Perl, `#include` in C, or `execfile` in Python when passing the current modules locals and globals, as though the referenced file was inserted directly into the current script.

Most existing solutions I can find out there refer to embeddeding these "includes" inside script tags, but I'm not sure this applies (and if it does, an explanation of where exactly my extension is injecting all these script tags in the current page).

### Update0

Note that I'm writing a content script. At least on the "user" side, I don't provide the original HTML document.

Comment: Given this is a Chrome extension why can't you just use static <script> tags for all the content you need?

Comment: @Lloyd it's a content script.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well the best solution was Chrome-specific. The javascript files are listed in the order they are loaded in the extension's [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html), here's an extract of the [relevant field](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration):

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js" : ["contentscript.js", "254195.user.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The javascript files are effectively concatenated in the order given and then executed.

Comment: So in contentscript.js we can call any var and function in 254195.user.js?

Comment: No, because contentscript.js loads before 254195.user.js. This works fine: "js" : ["jquery.js", "my-module.js", "main.js"]. So, jquery could be used in my-module.js, and my-module.js can be used in main.js.

Answer (score -1):

```
function load_script (url, cache) 
{ 

    var httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
    httpRequest.open('GET', url, false); 

    if(!cache)
    {
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
    }

    httpRequest.send(null);
    eval(httpRequest.responseText); 

    var s = httpRequest.responseText.split(/\n/); 
    var r = /^function\s*([a-z_]+)/i; 

    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
    { 
        var m = r.exec(s[i]); 
        if (m != null) 
        {
            window[m[1]] = eval(m[1]); 
        }
    }
}

load_script("/script.js",true);
```

We use this at our organization to do this.  Seems to work well enough.

Comment: Our application was IE only. Good catch.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try :

```
<script language="javascript" src="otherfile.js">
```

or (I'm not sure which... but I recall one of them working)

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="otherfile.js"></script>');
```

Comment: This clobbers the entire page, and it vanishes.